# Is this a well-known group? $\langle a,b \mid a^5=b^4=e,b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider the group $$
G=\langle a,b \mid a^5=b^4=e,b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle
$$
It looks like a dihedral group but it is not isomorphic to a dihedral group. Is this a well-known group?

Comment: See the list here: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_20

Comment: It has 20 elements, so it _ought_ to be known. Classifying it (there are three non-abelian order-20 groups, by the looks of it) is a different proposition, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$It's called a [dicyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group). You can see it by noting that $b^{-2} a b^{2} = b^{-1} a^{-1} b = a$, so that $a b^{2} = b^{2} a$, and then taking $c = a b^{2}$, and rewriting the presentation as
$$
\Span{
c, b : c^{10} = e, b^{2} = c^{5}, b^{-1} c b = c^{-1}
}
$$

Answer (score 3):

The group is the semidirect product of a cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$ of order $5$ and a cyclic group $\langle b \rangle$ of order $4$, where $b$ acts on $\langle a \rangle$ by an automorphism of order $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tool for you to use in future: [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/).

It describes the group as isomorphic to a semidirect product of $\Bbb Z_5$ and $\Bbb Z_4$ as delineated in @spin's answer.

Look:

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup(2);
<free group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> rel:=[F.1^5, F.2^4, F.2^-1*F.1*F.2*F.1];
[ f1^5, f2^4, f2^-1*f1*f2*f1 ]
gap> G:=F/rel;
<fp group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> StructureDescription(G);
"C5 : C4"
gap> IdGroup(G);
[ 20, 1 ]
```

The latter identification, via known libraries like [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_20), gives the dicyclic group of order twenty.

Comment: GAP is an essential tool for my own research work. Still, a caveat in this particular case. The GAP command List(AllSmallGroups(20), StructureDescription); yields [ "**C5 : C4**", "C20", "**C5 : C4**", "D20", "C10 x C2" ] showing that the description does not distinguish the two semidirect, non-direct products of $C_{5}$ by $C_{4}$, the difference being of course whether an element of order $4$ induces on the subgroup of order $5$ an automorphism of order $2$ or $4$.

Comment: Thank you, @AndreasCaranti; that's why I said "*a* semidirect product". Nonetheless, I have augmented this answer using `IdGroup(G);`. This identifies the group specifically to be the one you describe.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti thank you for pointing that out! A good further reading is [7.12: Can non-isomorphic groups have equal structure descriptions?](https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.12) from the GAP F.A.Q.